# Can I use the apple watch (with OS 4) as nfc wristband?

Tags: nfc, apple-watch, rfid

Can I read the rfid from an apple watch?
I tried using nfc reader but i am getting a different tag code/data every time.
I know that core NFC allow iPhone to read nfc.
But I want the use the apple watch as an nfc card/wristband, 
Is there a way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from Richard. [link to answer](https://flomio.com/forums/topic/read-nfc-from-apple-watch/)

the only way to use apple watch as nfc tag is with Apple Wallet.

Comment: The link leads to broken YouTube video.